# Насколько сильно мой скрипт jquery .load нагружает систему?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос, как по мне элементарно понятный. Мне нужно знать, нагружает ли мой скрип систему пользователя, то-есть, будет ли лагать этот скрипт на слабом пк. Или нагрузка идет только когда скрипт видит изменения в контенте? В блоке `#mainContentPosts` выводятся данные с БД, и на этой же странице, они добавляются в таблицу.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#mainContentPosts").load(location.href+" #mainContentPosts>*","");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: по какому принципу у вас данные обновляются на сервере? Может это например подгрузка новых данных, а может правки старых. В любом случае тут а) можно с запросом передавать время предыдушего, и чтобы сервер сам понимал и отдавал только изменившееся. Получили пустой ответ - ничего делать не надо. б) на крайний случай, можно сравнивать текущий контент блока с пришедшим, и заменять только при необходимости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не думаю, что это должно как-то нагружать систему. Но и всё сильно зависит от того насколько большие данные приходят на вход, как долго обрабатывается запрос. Представьте, что ответ с сервера обрабатывается 3 или более секунд, тогда у вас просто будет выглядеть как вечная загрузка :)

Как минимум чтобы избежать такого могу порекомендовать использовать `complete` у [.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) и заменить `setInterval` на рекурсивный `setTimeout`. Так вы сможете гарантированно сделать следующий запрос, спустя 3 секунды после получения ответа с сервера, а так же например перестать посылать запросы, если произошла какая-та ошибка